# understanding ways to use cypher query in embedded neo4j app

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

As far as I know there are 3 ways to run cypher query in with embedded java app.

1. `org.neo4j.driver.Session session = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, AuthTokens.basic(user, password)).session().run(query)`
   src,chatgpt

- known limitations,unable to use along with embedded neo4j app,since it needs user and password,I asssume it needs a neo4j/opencypher compatible server.

2. `new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(STORE_DIR).execute(query)`
   src,[Neo4j slow cypher query in embedded mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400856/neo4j-slow-cypher-query-in-embedded-mode)

- known limitations, excute(query); seems to not be in the current new api?https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/5.6/community/graphdb-api/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.java

3. `try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) then org.neo4j.graphdb.Result result=tx.execute(query);`
   src,written by myself based on existing api,https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/5.6/community/graphdb-api/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.java

- known limitations, practically 99% of the codes needs to be rewritten since org.neo4j.graphdb.Result != org.neo4j.driver.Result and the api seems to be different.

So the main question is

---

- are there other better simpler ways to run cypher query that I didnt list here?
- I am very new to database.Is my analysis of the limitations is (wrong/correct)?

I believe some SO members might frown with 2 questions*.However I believed that the context is very important and it will clearly show my attempts and what I currently understood as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the [neo4j Java API](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/5/javadocs/index.html) with an embedded neo4j DB, not the [Java Driver API](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/5/javadocs/index.html) (which is only for accessing un-embedded DBs).

The correct way to use Cypher with an embedded DB is [documented here](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/cypher-java/).

Comment: huge thanks it cleared up some of my confusion and thanks for giving the correct docs.